# What is this component on acer motherboard

Tags: transistors

can someone please help me with this and advice what is this component marked as Q81
[image]

Comment: Q is usually used for transistors.

Comment: According to [part databases][1]it could also be a linear regulator. Can you provide a bit of context for this question, or at least a picture that is a bit more zoomed out? Most of the time components can be identified by positioning on the board and following the traces.


  [1]: https://smd.yooneed.one/code3031.html

Comment: @Boldar If it was a linear regulator, it wouldn't have a Q for its refdes; integrated circuits of all types are almost always U. This is definitely a transistor of some sort.